# Change language / locale of pgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin

Just installed postgres in a windows box, 8.3.14-1, started up pgAdmin and it is in my local language (PT) instead of english like I wanted.

How can I change this?

(Note that: lc_messages = 'English, United States')

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Worth pointing out that it seems it has since changed to:

1- Open `File` > `Options`.

2- Change `User Interface` as in the image below.

3- Restart pgAdmin

[image]

Comment: Any idea on how to do the same for the "Application Stack Builder"

Comment: Hi,
I have the same problem. I did it and I set the user Language, but still I get error messages in output pane in another language (German) :(

Comment: Did you reset pgAdmin?

Answer (score 11):

1. Open pgadmin.
2. File > Options
3. Change 'user language'

Comment: This was true at the time of writing. Current versions of pgadmin are a bit different. I accepted a new answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Any idea on how to do the same for the "Application Stack Builder"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **pgAdmin4**, the GUI / web page does not provide an option to change language yet. You need to [modify the `config_local.py` file](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs4/dev/desktop_deployment.html) instead.

```python
# add this to `config_local.py` to force English, by removing other languages.
LANGUAGES = {'en': 'English'}
```

Restart pgAdmin4 after saving.

Comment: Making changes in config file is not recommended, instead make sure that during database defination you give correct langauge options

Comment: There is no config_local.py file, at least with pgAdmin4 version 25 on Windows

Answer (score 0):

For pgAdmin4(version 4.8) :
File > Preferences > Miscellaneous > User language

Answer (score 0):

Go to Server -> Configure pgAdmin -> Miscellaneous -> Language 
[image]

Comment: For what version? this is a very old question so probably things changed in.... 8 years :)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to change the interface language : File - Preferences - User Language
2. If you want to change the messages language:

- Open file \Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py
- Edit part "Languages we support in the UI" and set necessary language like that:
  LANGUAGES = {
  'en': 'English'
  }

3. If you want to change the error language:
   ALTER DATABASE 'db_name' SET lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'; // set your language