# pgadmin text shows right to left

Tags: right-to-left, pgadmin

I installed pgAdmin on windows 7 pro.
When I open the application all the text shows in mirror - from right to left.
My windows supports Hebrew, but I tried to install the application with locale English USA - still not working.
Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 14):

Try changing the user language in pgAdmin options to us_en

1. Open pgadmin.
2. File > Options
3. Miscellaneous > User Interface
4. Change 'User language'

(From https://stackoverflow.com/a/21848961)

Comment: works for me (same issue with Hebrew as default lang). Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the user language in pgAdmin options to en_us

1. Open pgadmin
2. file >> options
3. change 'user interface' to (en_us) english