# Pgadmin displaying errors in Swedish even after changing the language to english

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In preferences i have set my language to English, but the errors are still displayed in Swedish

```
ERROR:  FEL:  syntaxfel vid eller nära "where"
LINE 2:  WHERE where id = 2;
```

only errors are displayed in Swedish everything else is in English, i dont understand why
anyone else facing/faced this issue ?

Comment: What version of pgadmin are you using? Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555497/change-language-locale-of-pgadmin ?

Comment: Yes, i already tried that. I'm using version pgadmin v4.19 on windows. I have tried adding the env variable as well but still error messages are on swedish.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have different settings for the client and the server locale.

The client locale is determined by the environment on the client (see the `locale` command on Unix machines).

Error messages are generated by the server, and they use the server locale, which is determined by the `lc_messages` database parameter.

You can set the default value in `postgresql.conf`, and you can use `SET` to change the setting for your session:

```
SET lc_messages = "C";
```

I recommend the setting `C` (or, equivalent, `POSIX`) for the standard English messages.

Comment: Thanks, but it dint work! I'm using version pgadmin v4.19 on windows. I have tried adding the env variable as well but still error messages are on swedish.

Comment: With pgAdmin, the solution with `SET` won't work so well, only inside the query tool where you ran `SET`. Try changing `postgresql.conf` and reloading.