# Incorrect encoding in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When I try to run a command in pgAdmin I have question marks instead of letters in the output window.
Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: likely related to this reasoning, non-ASCII(https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258616/why-is-postgresql-limited-to-ascii-only-characters-for-the-application-name/258624) is not printed. which locale is your system, and did you install pgAdmin in that language?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555497/change-language-locale-of-pgadmin

Answer (score 2):

Before : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\share\locale

After : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\share\_locale

In my case, Change 'locale' directory name. It works well.

Comment: Brilliant solution! It does not FIX locale it just delete all locales and WOW - you can see normal english messages :)))

Comment: 16 version works